# [autoware.auto] cannot launch LGSVL simulator

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the instructions here:

https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/lgsvl.html

And I run the simulator binary I get the window with the 'Open Browser' button, but when I click the button, nothing happens. It seems very similar to this problem:

https://github.com/lgsvl/simulator/issues/319

But I'm not sure how to apply that resolution to a docker container. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345423/%5Bautoware.auto%5D-cannot-launch-lgsvl-simulator/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2020-02-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-03-01**:
What happens if you manually open a browser and go to http://localhost:8080?

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2020-03-01**:
It redirects to a login page on https://account.lgsvlsimulator.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The button may not work correctly within Docker. However, you can open a browser and navigate to http://localhost:8080. The new behavior is that this will redirect to https://account.lgsvlsimulator.com/. You will need to create a login for this site if you have not already using the "Sign Up" link at the top of the page. Once you've created this account, you can log in and configure the simulator as before.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2020-03-01**:
Thanks, that seems to do it.